# Python, Convert String Into List of Dictionaries, Insert One Dictionary Into Django Model

Tags: django, dictionary, model

I have the following string received from an ajax post in a django view (*its 2 rows of a angular ui-grid*):

```
data=[{"part_name":"33029191913","id":"5","qty":"3","ticket":"","comments":"test"},
{"part_name":"3302919777","id":"3","qty":"323","ticket":"","comments":"test"}]
```

Then doing `json.loads(data)` that gives me the following:

```
data={'part_name': '33029191913', 'id': '5', 'qty': '3', 'ticket': '', 'comments': 'test'}
{'part_name': '3302919777', 'id': '3', 'qty': '323', 'ticket': '', 'comments': 'test'}
```

Without specifying each field in order to create a dictionary, I want to create one that looks like the following in order to insert it into my model, via `MyModel(**data)`:

```
{'part_name': '33029191913', 'id': '5', 'qty': '3', 'ticket': '', 'comments': 'test'}
```

After json.loads(data), if i try to access one element (eg. `data[0]['part_name']`), it correctly shows '33029191913', but if I do `data[0]` or `data[1]`, it gives me only the apparent keys:
`part_nameidqtyticketcomments`.

How can I separate the string received by ajax into dictionaries in order to insert them into the django model?

Answer (score 0):

Taking this json string from a post:

```
data=[{"part_name": "part 1", "part_id": "1", "quantity": "233", "ticket": "32", "comments": "32"}{"part_name": "part 1", "part_id": "1", "quantity": "233", "ticket": "32", "comments": "32"}]
```

grid=ast.literal_eval(data)   returns:

```
{'part_name': 'part 1', 'part_id': '1', 'quantity': '233', 'ticket': '32', 'comments': '32'}{'part_name': 'part 1', 'part_id': '1', 'quantity': '233', 'ticket': '32', 'comments': '32'}
```

Assuming that the keys on the ajax json string are the same as your model fields(only the 'part_name' field is not in the model, and hardcoding the order_id foreign key for test purposes):

```
    for d in grid:
        object_insert={}
        for key in d:
            object_insert[key]=d[key]
            object_insert['order_id']=1
        del object_insert['part_name']
        order=Order_Detail(**object_insert)
        order.save()
```

This saves the dictionary in the model without having to specify each of the keys.